# Golang one line for loop

Tags: for-loop, go, coding-style

I was trying to read in CSV file in Golang line by line with a for loop that required an if statement with a break to see if the error reading the file was EOF.  I find this syntax rather unnecessary when I could in java for example read the line inside a while loop conditional and simultaneously check for the EOF error.  I thought that declaring a variable inside of a for loop was possible and I know for sure that you can do this with if statements in Golang. Doing:

```
if v := 2; v > 1{
    fmt.Println("2 is better than 1")
}
```

The first snippet of code I have here is what I know to work in my program.

```
reader := csv.NewReader(some_file)

for {
    line, err := reader.Read()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    //do data parsing from your line here
}
```

I do not know whether or not this second snippet is conceptually possible or just syntactically incorrect.

```
reader := csv.NewReader(some_file)

for line, err := reader.Read(); err != io.EOF {
    //do data parsing from your line here
}
```

Would like some clarification/benefits/conventions of doing it one way over another, Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try it? The for-loop is versatile. You would need an extra `;`, though.

Comment: The second version is not Go. Most people would write a variant of the first code.

Comment: You mean something like this?: https://play.golang.org/p/Uly1buDNXCF -- Sure it's possible if you write a valid for statement, whether that's useful or not is debatable.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You have to repeat the Read call: https://play.golang.org/p/Uc51FFTBM_9. I don't see how this is in any way better than your first version though. Multiple short lines are preferable over a single long line and, more importantly, the error handling is incomplete (any error other than EOF is ignored).

Answer (score 0):

It is conventional way to write simpler statements rather than lengthy, complex one, isn't it?

So, I consider the 1st version is more conventional way than the 2nd version. Moreover, the `for` loop in your 2nd version isn't in the right way. If you want to use that, then fix it like following or whatever you wish:

```
for line, err := reader.Read(); err != io.EOF; line, err = reader.Read() {
    //do data parsing from your line here
}
```